# Laravel: scope method with traits

Tags: laravel, methods, scope, traits

! have a trait called `ModelScrops` where I have some of the common methods to be associated with the models. I recently learnt about the `scope` functionality. So, I am trying to implement it but I am getting this error:

```php
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::addedBy()
```

Here is my code:

```php
...

trait ModelScrops
{
    ...

    public function scopeAddedBy($query)
    {
        return $query->select([
            \DB::raw("(
                CASE `{$this->table}`.`employable_type`
                    WHEN 'C' THEN `companies`.`name`
                    ELSE CONCAT(`employees`.`name`, ' [ ', `employees`.`code`,  ' ]')
                END
            ) AS `added_by`")
        ]);
    }

    ...
}
```

Model:

```php
use App\Traits\ModelScrops;

...

class Device extends Model
{
    use ModelScrops;

    ...

    public function show($token)
    {
         return \DB::table($this->table)
            ->where("{$this->table}.token", $token)

            ...

            ->addedBy()
            ->get() ?? null;
    }
}
```

I even tried to put the `scopeAddedBy` method in the `Device` model but the error is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scopes are for use with Eloquent Models not Query Builder directly. You are doing a query directly with Query Builder: `DB::table(...)`. You want to build this query using your model and you will have access to your Scopes.

```
return static::where('token', $token)
    ...
    ->addedBy()
    ->get();
```

Or even:

```
return $this->newQuery()->where(...)->.....;
```

Side note: `get` always returns a Collection.

Comment: Thanks @lagbox. But, I need this method to be global bcz most of my models need this functionality. How do I do that..? I don't want to repeat the code over and over again..

Comment: the problem with your question is your are NOT querying with your model, literally are not involving the model at all  ... there is no such things as Scopes on Query Builder ... if you want to add a new 'method' to Query Builder you can 'macro' one in  :)